# Simple API to write a file in Clojure Luminus

Tags: rest, clojure, asp.net-web-api, luminus

As a beginning for learning Luminus, I am trying to create a simple API for interacting with the local server environment. Writing a basic file seems like a good way to start, but I can't get it to work. See my code from `home.clj`:

```
(defroutes test-routes
  (GET "/spit/:file-name/:file-text" [file-name file-text] 
    (spit file-name file-text) 
    {:status 200
    :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8"}
    :body (str "File name: " file-name "<br />File text: " file-text)}))
```

Luminus returns just two words `Not Found`.

A second example that also isn't working:

```
(defroutes test-routes
  (GET "/spit" [] 
     (spit "test.txt" "test")
     {:status 200
      :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8"}
      :body (str "File name: "  "<br />File text: " )}))
```

Answer (score 3):

I just figured this out. The issue was that `test-routes` was not properly added to `handler.clj`. So I referred the symbol `test-routes` from `home.clj` and added `test-routes` to the vector of routes symbols in the `app-handler` call.

I also figured out that the ring server needs to be restarted sometimes to get changes to show up in the application. Routes also seem to have to be listed before `app-routes`.